# How to get this system.list exception error?

Tags: apex, exception

```
public PageReference save1(){
    //Local varibles and instance
    //UtilityClass.isCreated =false; 
    List<Quote_Line_item__c> qlirowIncrement=[Select id,QliRowNum__c from Quote_Line_Item__c where Quote1__c=:parentId ORDER BY QliRowNum__c LIMIT 50000];

    transient List<Quote_Line_item__c> listtoinsert =new List<Quote_Line_item__c>();
    transient List<Batch__c> batchListToInsert =new List<Batch__c>();
    transient List<Integer> sortkey=new List<Integer>();
    sortkey.addAll(qouteLineItemMap.keySet());
    //Sorting the list of quote line item  keys to insert the QuoteLineItems in an order
    sortkey.sort();

    Integer rowCount=qlirowIncrement.size();
    rowCount++;
    for(integer key : sortkey){
        if(qouteLineItemMap.containsKey(key) && qouteLineItemMap.get(key)!=null){
            qouteLineItemMap.get(key).QliRowNum__c = rowCount;
            rowCount++;
        }
    }

    //Iterating the loop to store the list of QuoteLineItems which are going to be inserted into the databse
    for(integer qli:sortkey){
     if(qouteLineItemMap.get(qli).Name!=Null){
        listtoinsert.add(qouteLineItemMap.get(qli));
        }
        // conditon to display the error when there is no batch for a particular QuoteLineItem
    }//End of for 

    // Inserting the list of QuoteLine Items
    try{
        upsert listtoinsert;
    } catch(DmlException de){
        return null;
    }
    //Iterating the loop to store the list of Batches which are going to be inserted into the databse
    for(integer qli:sortkey){
        for(Batchwrapper bat: batchMap.get(qli)){
            if(bat.batchobj.Asked_Qty__c!=Null){
            bat.batchObj.Quote_Line_Item__c=qouteLineItemMap.get(qli).id;
            }
            batchListToInsert.add(bat.batchObj);
        }//End of for 
    }// End of for
    // Inserting the list of batches
    try{
    if(batchListToInsert.size()>0){
      upsert batchListToInsert ;
      }
    }catch(DmlException de){
        return null;
    }
}//End of method
```

> System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two
>   identically equal elements

It was throwing error in this part  **upsert batchListToInsert ;**  .

How to get this error ?

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1):

In your list same record inserted more then one times that's why this error is coming. You can assign this list to Set and then reconvert it into list and then insert. You need to check your logic because you have nested for loops so its very good chance that you will get this error.

Also **batchMap** variable is not available so what record you save in this map.